Does the base version of Age of Mythology: Retold include the "Tale of the Dragon" expansion from Age of Mythology: Extended Edition?
I'm looking at Age of Mythology: Retold (2024) on Steam, which has a base and "Premium" versions. According to the roadmap, Premium edition comes with "Expansion 1 and Expansion 2":


The Premium Edition includes the full game, New exclusive Gods Pack: Freyr, Legacy Deity Portraits Pack, Expansion 1 (all-new Chinese pantheon expansion) and Expansion 2 (additional new pantheon).

However, Age of Mythology: Extended Edition (2014) had a Chinese expansion pack: "Tales of the Dragon", which featured a new Chinese civilisation, pantheon, and a new campaign. I'm trying to figure out if this old expansion content is included in the base game of Retold, or whether they are repackaging the old expansion campaign as "Expansion 1"
Can anyone confirm: Does the base game of Retold include the Tales of the Dragon content?

It looks like they're scrapping Tale of the Dragon entirely; the base game in Retold only comes with "gods from the Greek, Norse, Egyptian, and Atlantean pantheons" from the Steam page linked in the question, and then expansion 1 is an "all-new" version of the Chinese pantheon, so not the Tale of the Dragon version.
